# looking for free source safe for visual web developer express 2008

Tags: visual-web-developer

I am using visual web developer express 2008 for one of my personal projects. I am looking for a source safe or similar product that is free and that can integrate with visual web developer 2008. Please let me know if you know any products.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Comment: Lots of suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566595/best-subversion-tool-when-using-visual-studio-express

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, extension points allowing for such integration are unavailable in VWD. That's the price for using free Express version...

In your place I would use Subversion and Tortoise SVN, which is quite convenient, even though you'll need to manage your source control in Explorer windows, not in VWD. For some time I was working in a such way even using full VS.NET

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There's simply nothing better then **Subversion**.

Take a look at the article on how to set it up and integrate with Visual Web Developer Express 2008
[Subversion with Visual Studio 2008](http://incsharp.blogspot.com/2007/11/subversion-visual-studio-2008.html)

Comment: I agree. Subversion i widely used among larger companies as well.

Comment: Unless you agree with Linus Torvalds and think Git is The Bomb.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to use git on windows though.